# Recive different type of objects on the same TCP socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

so here is the deal:
I have a server running that is constantly accepting clients by TCP socket:

```
public ArrayList<Socket> lista_users = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

Socket s;

```
            s = serverSocket.accept();

            lista_users.add(s);
            avisa_all(lista_users, s);

            Thread t_trata_cliente = new Thread(new trata_cliente(lista_users, s));
            t_trata_cliente.start(); //this Thread is responsable for interacting with
                                    //the clients (where my question is)
```

Saving the sockets on array list.
After i want to send different type of information to my clients(Thread "trata_cliente").
When i say different type of information i mean, first send a warning message, then an object, then some message, then object again.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is the receiver a java application as well?

Comment: yes it is a java based client.

Comment: There's no "best" protocol. There's the "densest" protocol that is hard to encode and decode (and version), then there's the Java's native serialisation protocol which is not efficient for short messages, then there's JSON, then there's deflated JSON...

Comment: Here is an example to explain myself better: Server accepted a client, if will send a notify message to all the client + (i am not sure if i have to send the new ArrayList of users again). Then when the server gets "message1" he sends an object(for example calendar) to all users, and so on...all this using ObjectOutputStream, if possible xd

Answer (score 4):

Encapsulate the output stream of the socket with the appropriate wrapper:

- [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html): To send primitive data type + Strings.
- [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html): To send objects through the stream.

Comment: That is correct under at least two definitions of "best". Upvoting.

Comment: But how do my client knows what type of object he is receiving? Because my server can send calendar type or data, or something else...i need a system so the client could identify the type of receiving object... Thanks

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin ObjectOutputStream handles the typing. You only need to do `instanceof` on the receiving end..

Comment: If the receiving end does not know whether to expect objects or primitive types, always send (and expect) objects.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin Simply, if you send an object via `ObjectOutputStrema`, then read it via `ObjectInputStream`.