# Sockets, Streams and object size/types

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm making a message app (surprise!) and there's strategies I'd like comments on.

1. Want to send different objects/classes... are inner classes the best way or sending different class objects and trapping(`ClassNotFoundException`) and retying? Currently I use a serializable class with 2 inner serializable classes to hold my two main class structures. The parent class holds holds a variable that tells what class to use on the other end of the stream.
2. Would it be best to use `ArrayList<MyObject>` for multiple messages or `MyObject[]` in the streams? I know `ArrayList` is serializable already.
3. Size of messages... this would be a mobile device to server. I want to keep message size as small as possible. Do methods take up a bunch of data size?

I want a nice, simple and data conserving/small multi-purpose socket message.

Just looking for best practice that isn't super complicated!

Comment: An inner `class` is by definition **not `static`**. This is a **massive issue**.  Any inner `class` will contain an implicit reference to its parent `class`. This will also be serialized - which can not only cause sending superfluous data but can be a massive security hole (password stored in parent class field anyone...). So I would suggest using specifically created, top level, classes for data transfer. `List` vs array is a non-question - doesn't matter. Java serialization is fairly efficient, but there are more efficient systems - for example protobuf.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why are you calling it a massive issue? It's a language design choice...

Comment: @BoristheSpider 
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SER05-J.+Do+not+serialize+instances+of+inner+classes

Serialized outer and inner static are OK this says

Comment: @fge I'm calling it a massive issue for the use case. Read my whole comment. I'm aware that it serves a purpose in the general case.

Comment: No overhead for methods - they're not serialized as they contain no data.

Comment: @kenyu73 yes, `static` would be fine. I would choose outer to be explicit. But you say, and I quote, "_are **inner classes** the best way_" (emphasis mine). I say they are not due to it being both a waste of data and a security leak waiting to happen.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If I have 2 completely different type of messages to send, say message and group_details, i'd want to organize them with two inner classes.. else somehow send two different socket messages which will err since I need to cast them one way or another, right?

Comment: @kenyu73 sorry, I don't understand the question. If the two classes are unrelated then whether they are outer, nested or inner does not change that - casting would still need to occur. But this is all moot to my point which was that it is **never** okay to serialize inner classes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I cast only the outer class in the streams... this will give me the option to use one of the inner classes after casting by checking if one or the other is null or by using a identifier in the parent class. Basically cast the parent and use the inner as needed. Make sense? Maybe this type of design is bad, but it works. This is why I thru this question out.. to see how others have done it.

receive = (MyObject)in.ReadObject();
ObjOne = receive.InnerObj;

Comment: similar object question - maybe just cast as Object, then use instanceOf checks... this way I can use top level classes only?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576596/recive-different-type-of-objects-on-the-same-tcp-socket?rq=1

Comment: You have *serializable* classes; `ArrayList` is *serializable* (and so are arrays). Don't misuse standard terminology.